# Cmake link wrong path of a pre built binary android

Tags: android, c++, cmake

I'm trying to add python on my android app using [PyBridge](https://github.com/joaoventura/pybridge). I compiled libpython3.8.so using python-for-android Docker container for ABI arm64-v8a armeabi-v7a with no error.
I successfully build a test apk using cmake for native library.

But when i run app on my phone I got this error

```
2022-01-29 14:09:42.066 23611-23611/com.manob.pythontest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.manob.pythontest, PID: 23611
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/Users/manobbiswas/AndroidStudioProjects/PythonTest/app/src/main/cpp/../libs/arm64-v8a/libpython3.8.so" not found: needed by /data/app/~~csjGY6aZ9p08Bug52yMA-Q==/com.manob.pythontest-IbjpbfFuiPALMmRIIt_C8A==/lib/arm64/libpythontest.so in namespace classloader-namespace
```

In errorlog I find path of libpython3.8.so `/Users/manobbiswas/AndroidStudioProjects/PythonTest/app/src/main/cpp/../libs/arm64-v8a/libpython3.8.so` instade of `/lib/arm64/libpython3.8.so`

hear is CmakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)
project("pythontest")
add_library(
        pythontest
        SHARED
        native-lib.cpp)

add_library(python3.8
        SHARED
        IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(python3.8
        PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libpython3.8.so )

include_directories(include/${ANDROID_ABI})

find_library(log-lib log)

target_link_libraries(pythontest python3.8 ${log-lib})
```

Comment: Usually you've got a copy of the target file system (or at least the relevant parts) lying around in some directory on the machine doing the compilation. In your case this doesn't seem to be the case. Any specific reaon why? Usually cmake adds some logic dealing with issues like this, if you set the sysroot in your toolchain file. (Not sure if this would be sufficient in your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens caused while building libpython3.8.so SONAME header wasn't set.

It can be verified by

`readelf -a libpython3.8.so`